# How run Protractor Test from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, protractor

I am new in Jenkins. I want run automatically my Protractor tests in Jenkins job.

This is my package.js file:

```
{
    "name": "ui",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build --prod",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e" 

    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/common": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "5.2.0",
        "bootstrap": "4.1.1",
        "core-js": "2.4.1",
        "jquery": "3.3.1",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
        "protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter": "0.0.7",
        "protractor-jasmine2-reporter": "^1.1.0",
        "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.5.0",

        "rxjs": "5.5.6",
        "zone.js": "0.8.19"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.7.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "5.2.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.8.3",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
        "@types/node": "6.0.60",
        "codelyzer": "4.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
        "karma": "2.0.2",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
        "protractor": "5.3.2",
        "ts-node": "4.1.0",
        "tslint": "5.9.1",
        "typescript": "2.5.3"
    }
}
```

This is my protractor.confing.js:

```
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],


  seleniumAddress: 'http://HubDomain-IP:4444/wd/hub',

  //Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',

    // add node-name as applicationName where you have started node and wanted to remotely execute test cases 
    'applicationName': 'remoteNode'
  },
  chromeDriver: 'C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver.exe',

seleniumServerJar: 'C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar',

  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function () { }
  },
  suites: {
    full: 'e2e/**/**/*.ts',
    powerMax200: 'e2e/tests/powerMax2000/*.ts',
    powerMax200: 'e2e/tests/powerMax8000/*.ts',
    vmax250f: 'e2e/tests/vmax250f/*.ts',
    vmax950f: 'e2e/tests/vmax950f/*.ts'
  },

  onPrepare() {
    var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

    require('ts-node').register({
      // project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json',
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
      savePath: './e2e/report',
      screenshotsFolder: 'images'
    }));

  }
};
```

In my Jenkins job I pull code from BitBucket repository. And I execute Windows batch commands:
1) cd NewGenProject/ui/
    npm install

2) cd NewGenProject/ui/
   npm -g install protractor

3) cd NewGenProject/ui/

npm install -g @angular/cli
  ./node_modules.bin\webdriver-manager update

And i have error in console :

```
Started by user Admin
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://___somi@bitbucket.org/night_riders/desingstudio_new_gen.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://___somi@bitbucket.org/night_riders/desingstudio_new_gen.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://___somi@bitbucket.org/night_riders/desingstudio_new_gen.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen branch in repository origin/application.properties
Seen branch in repository origin/develop
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 3 remote branches
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe show-ref --tags -d # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 4af5b739aa52943c28f58d128d5f28bffa095463 (origin/application.properties)
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f 4af5b739aa52943c28f58d128d5f28bffa095463
Commit message: "a"
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list --no-walk 4af5b739aa52943c28f58d128d5f28bffa095463 # timeout=10
System is not Unix, Xvfb will not be started
[newGen_protractor] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins205557989357167568.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor>cd NewGenProject/ui/ 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui>npm install 
npm WARN @angular/http@5.2.11 requires a peer of @angular/core@5.2.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/http@5.2.11 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@5.2.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@3.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@3.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

audited 7548 packages in 39.325s
found 8 vulnerabilities (2 low, 5 moderate, 1 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
[newGen_protractor] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins6721521287779075208.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor>cd NewGenProject/ui/ 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui>npm -g install protractor 
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\protractor -> C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\webdriver-manager -> C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager
+ protractor@5.4.1
updated 1 package in 15.574s
[newGen_protractor] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins3967655168792638034.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor>cd NewGenProject/ui/ 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui>npm install -g @angular/cli 
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/cli@6.2.2
updated 1 package in 41.598s
[newGen_protractor] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins7519801179326584034.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor>cd NewGenProject/ui/ 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui>ng e2e --no-webdriver-update 
Your global Angular CLI version (6.2.1) is greater than your local
version (1.7.3). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:49156, open your browser on http://localhost:49156/ **
[0mDate: [1m[37m2018-09-18T11:33:38.940Z[39m[22m[0m
[0mHash: [1m[37mb824d4ffc831966e2310[39m[22m[0m
[0mTime: [1m[37m32450[39m[22mms[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33minline[39m[22m} [1m[32minline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map[39m[22m (inline) 3.89 kB [1m[33m[entry][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33mmain[39m[22m} [1m[32mmain.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map[39m[22m (main) 240 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33mpolyfills[39m[22m} [1m[32mpolyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map[39m[22m (polyfills) 203 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33mscripts[39m[22m} [1m[32mscripts.bundle.js, scripts.bundle.js.map[39m[22m (scripts) 158 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33mstyles[39m[22m} [1m[32mstyles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map[39m[22m (styles) 158 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33mvendor[39m[22m} [1m[32mvendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map[39m[22m (vendor) 6.04 MB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
(node:3240) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.

webpack: Compiled successfully.
[13:33:39] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[13:33:39] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[13:33:39] E/direct - Error code: 135
[13:33:39] E/direct - Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
[13:33:39] E/direct - Error: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
    at Direct.getNewDriver (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:63:31)
    at Runner.createBrowser (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
[13:33:39] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: You should not create new question for same issue, So far you had create 3 questions for this issue.  You should update the description/information after each new finding.

Comment: To resolve your issue,  get the source on local, and open a window cmd window,  type & execute below 4 cmd lines one by one, If they can fix your issue, the same cmd lines should work in jenkins too.   `cd NewGenProject/ui/ ` ,       `npm install`,      `node_modules\.bin\webdriver-manager update` ,     
       `node_moduels\.bin\ng e2e --no-webdriver-update`

Comment: I pull code on local. First , second and third command  works fine. Just last command does not work. Command work just with e2e --no-webdriver-update

Comment: Do you have idea how resolve this problem?

Comment: OK, change your package.json to replace `"@angular/cli": "1.7.3",` with  `"@angular/cli": "6.2.2",`, then delete or rename the folder: `node_modules`, then execute the second, third and forth cmd again

Comment: I have this error : The module 'node_moduels' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module
node_moduels'.

Comment: which cmd report this error?

Comment: This : node_moduels\.bin\ng e2e --no-webdriver-update

Comment: I made a type mistake on `node_moduels `,  It should be `node_modules\.bin\ng e2e --no-webdriver-update`

Comment: Now I have new error : Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.

Comment: So, there is no file: `angular.json` under folder `NewGenProject/ui`?  I'm not sure this file is only required by high version of Angular cli like `6.2.2`  but not required by lower version like `1.7.3`.   You can roll back the changes on `package.json` to use lower version, then repeat operations again.

Comment: No, does have. Angular project have .angular-cli.json file

Comment: I have `angular.json` in my local project which used angular cli 6.1.5. I never try angular cli 1.x.   This file will auto-generated when you use angular cli `ng new app_name` to create an angular application project.   I guess lower version require `angular-cli.json`, high version require `angular.json`.  So change package.json to original lower version `1.7.3`. rename node_modules,  execute last 3 cmds again.  Please notice the typing mistake in the forth cmd.

Comment: Very  interesting but with version 1.7.3 command :node_modules\.bin\ng e2e --no-webdriver-update, work fine.

Comment: Do you know what now ?

Comment: Because your protractor conf.js specify `directConnect: true` which will try to launch the webdriver binary,  but these binary will not installed along with protractor installing. You need to execute `webdriver-manager update` to get them installed.  And Angular-Cli lower version won't  execute `webdriver-manager update` automatically for you.   But high version will update as default setting.

Comment: When to launch webdriver binary,  it need to read the `update-config.json` to know the  file path of webdriver binary which your update at the last time.   The `update-config.json`  will be created for the first time when execute `webdriver-manager update`, and be updated for later  `webdriver-manager update`

Comment: You specify `browserName: 'chrome'` in protractor conf.js,  it will try to find the file path of  webdriver binary: `chromedriver._xxx.exe` from `update-config.json` before launch it.

Comment: you can find `update-config.json` from `node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/` after execute `webdriver-manager update` success at least one time

Comment: Ok, now I understood what is problem. Your opinion is In Jenkins job I need to add webdriver-manager update command?

Comment: yes,  to get the webdriver binary to be installed,  or for Angular 1.x, you can try `node_modules\.bin\ng e2e --webdriver-update`  to make angular cli to do that for you, then you no need to execute  `webdriver-manager update`.  More detail for Angular CLI 1.x document about `ng e2e` can find from https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/1-x-e2e

Comment: Thanks a lot. This work for me. :))

Answer (score 1):

Change following 3 cmd lines in Jenkins job:

```
cd NewGenProject/ui/
npm install
node_moduels\.bin\ng e2e --webdriver-update
```